# Creating a dropdown list whose op tions are depenedent on another list in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a dropdown list to select State which is dependent on the another dropdown list Country.

Based on the Country selected from the first list, the second dropdown list should display corresponding states of the country.

For both the dropdown list i need to fetch values from the SQL server database.

Here is the code am trying:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){


               $("#country").change(function(){
                     var country=$("#country").val();
                     $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"getcity.php",
                        data:"country="+country,
                        success:function(data){
                              $("#city").html(data);
                        }
                     });
               });
           });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        Country :
        <select name="country" id="country">
          <option>-select your country-</option>

        <?php 

        include "dbconfig.php"; 

        $sql = "SELECT [CountryId],[Country] from Country order by [Country]";
        $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
        while($country = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){

        echo "<option value = $country[CountryId]>$country[Country]</option>";

        } ?>
        </select>


        City :
        <select name="city" id="city">
            <option>-select your city-</option>
        </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the getcity.php code :

```
<?php

 include "dbconfig.php";

 $country=$_POST["country"];

 $sql= "select [StateID],[State] from State where CountryId='$country'";
 $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
 while($city=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo"<option value='$city[StateID]'>$city[State]</option>";
 }

?>
```

I made database connection code in the file dbconnection.php and it is working fine, successfully connected with the database.

My problem is:

When i run this code i am not able to get the dropdown list of states after selecting the country.

The code doesn't return any error even though dropdown list of state not appear after selecting the country.

Please suggest me where i went wrong hopefully it will helps me a lot.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console? Any errors?

Comment: Yes i do, but not getting any errors.

Comment: Do you see the results of the second query returned in the response? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` My bet is your actual query is not correct. What are the `[]` for?

Comment: @JayBlanchard : Thanks for ur reply, Query is working fine i have checked it. Please any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the options to the selectbox instead of setting it's HTML. Replace; `$("#city").html(data);` by `$("#city").append(data);`. I hope this helps.